# Firestore field delete only making the field null instead of removing

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I have a script which is being weird! When I run it, it won't delete the field on the document but instead sets the field to `null`. Never seen this before.

Code:

```
await firebase
     .firestore()
     .collection('devices')
     .doc('W4ajAVxml4Mffwnqfo23')
     .update({
          exampleField: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete(),
     });
```

This should result in `exampleField` being removed from document `W4ajAVxml4Mffwnqfo23` in the collection `devices`. Instead, it's value is set to `null`.

From package.json:
`"firebase": "^8.2.1"`

Package.json contents:

```
{
    "name": "app",
    "version": "1.18.76",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
        "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
        "functions": "firebase serve --only functions --port 5001"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@capacitor-community/bluetooth-le": "^1.8.2",
        "@capacitor-community/fcm": "^2.0.2",
        "@capacitor-community/http": "^1.4.1",
        "@capacitor-community/keep-awake": "^2.1.1",
        "@capacitor/android": "^3.5.1",
        "@capacitor/app": "1.1.1",
        "@capacitor/camera": "^1.3.1",
        "@capacitor/core": "3.5.1",
        "@capacitor/device": "^1.1.2",
        "@capacitor/filesystem": "^1.1.0",
        "@capacitor/haptics": "1.1.4",
        "@capacitor/ios": "^3.5.1",
        "@capacitor/keyboard": "1.2.2",
        "@capacitor/network": "^1.0.7",
        "@capacitor/push-notifications": "^1.0.9",
        "@capacitor/splash-screen": "^1.2.2",
        "@capacitor/status-bar": "1.0.8",
        "@capacitor/storage": "^1.2.5",
        "@ionic/pwa-elements": "^3.1.1",
        "@ionic/vue": "^6.0.0",
        "@ionic/vue-router": "^6.0.0",
        "@robingenz/capacitor-badge": "^1.2.1",
        "@sentry/cli": "^2.0.4",
        "@sentry/tracing": "^7.1.1",
        "@sentry/vue": "^7.1.1",
        "axios": "^0.27.2",
        "buffer": "^6.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic": "^5.5.2",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.5",
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
        "firebase": "^8.10.1",
        "google-polyline": "^1.0.3",
        "mapbox-gl": "^2.8.2",
        "marked": "^4.0.15",
        "vue": "^3.2.21",
        "vue-json-pretty": "^2.1.1",
        "vue-router": "^4.0.12"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@capacitor/cli": "3.5.1",
        "@sentry/webpack-plugin": "1.18.4",
        "@types/jest": "^27.0.2",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.6.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.6.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0-rc.1",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "~5.0.0-rc.1",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0-rc.1",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0-rc.1",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~5.0.0-rc.1",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~5.0.0-rc.1",
        "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0-rc.1",
        "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^9.1.0",
        "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-rc.16",
        "@vue/vue3-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.3",
        "babel-jest": "^27.3.1",
        "cypress": "^8.7.0",
        "eslint": "^8.4.1",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.2.0",
        "jest": "^27.3.1",
        "ts-jest": "^27.0.7",
        "typescript": "^4.3.5"
    },
    "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

This is an Ionic 6 project btw. Not sure if that matters but it uses the Firebase JavaScript NPM package.

Comment: This has nothing to do with security rules.  Rules simply either allow or reject some requested action to happen.  They don't change the way that something would happen successfully.  It might help if you edit the question to explain in more detail what isn't working the way you expect, using screenshots and actual values instead of variables.  We should be able to duplicate the behavior using the instructions you provide in the question.

Comment: @DougStevenson Not sure how to elaborate anymore. I run the code, the field becomes `null` rather than being removed from the document. Literally that simple.

Comment: You can elaborate by showing us exactly what you observe.  You could hard code the values of the variables so we don't have to assume that you're using the values that you think you're using.  Also we can't see your database before or after the code runs.  Help us reproduce, without assumptions, what you observe by being concrete and specific about everything you see and execute.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am so confused. I literally explain everything leaving no assumptions. Fine, I'll edit my question but the resultant does not change. This is such a strange request.

Comment: Actually what I'm requesting is pretty common for SO questions to include.  It's  well documented here to provide a [complete minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  What you had was minimal, but not complete.  It might be helpful also to show a screenshot of the console that proves that what you're saying is true about the document that was modified.  Sometimes people are looking at the wrong document, or are misinterpreting what's there.  This is similar to showing any program logging output that helps us trace the flow of data end to end.

Comment: @DougStevenson Ok. I've edited the question. Let's leave the comments for those with answers and not question requests. Thanks!

Comment: Asking for clarifications like this is exactly what the comments are for on Stack Overflow.  Answers go below in a separate section.  Comments != answers.  I still don't see any screenshots of documents though, or anything that would help visualize your data end to end.

Comment: Can you provide your complete `package.json` in your question? Tried to reproduce the code above but it successfully deletes the field and does not produce `null` values using the Firebase version you're using.

Comment: @TylerC I still can't reproduce your issue, I would suggest you to contact [Firebase Support] https://firebase.google.com/support instead.